# Как учитывать часовой пояс пользователя при выводе ответа?

Tags: javascript, discord, momentjs

Делаю дискорд-бота. Группы людей находятся в разных часовых поясах. Периодически идет запись времени собеседования. Тем, кто за пределами Московского часового пояса, приходится вручную считать время и записывать его относительно Московского. Пытаюсь сделать так, что при команде записи бот выдавал время сам относительно Московского, но чтобы так считалось только для МСК часового пояса, а для своего человек локально продолжал видеть свое время. Возможно ли так сделать? Видел ботов, которые как-то изменяют время.
Пишу с применненим moment.js
Пробовал со смещением времени `moment().utcOffset(5);` - не видит время вообще
С отображением таймзоны  и указанием локально,  и `moment.utc().format();`
Может, кто-то объяснить, как в данном случае выводить для каждого региона свое время одной и той же записи и возможно ли это?
Потому что можно задать роли с учетом пояса, чтобы при записи сразу минусовало на нужное кол-во часов, но тут самое важное, чтобы тайминг для каждого пояса оставался своим.

Comment: Такая вот статейка тебе поможет? https://runebook.dev/ru/docs/moment_timezone/

Comment: Это и искал, только в обратную сторону правда не разобрался как сделать